# How to debug Vue CLI 3 unit tests with WebStorm? Debugger doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webstorm, jestjs, vue-cli-3

**Question**

1. What do I have to do to make WebStorm hit the breakpoint?
2. Is it necessary to set the %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%? If yes, how do I do this in combination with vue-cli.service?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. vue create myapp

   - Set options to:

     - ? Please pick a preset: **Manually select features**
     - ? Check the features needed for your project: **Babel, Unit**
     - ? Pick a unit testing solution: **Jest**
     - ? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, PostCSS, ESLint, etc.? **In package.json**
     - ? Save this as a preset for future projects? **No**
2. Open myapp in WebStorm
3. Open npm Tool Windows
4. Set breakpoint in tests/unit/example.spec.js
5. Rightclick on test:unit->Debug test:unit

**console output:**

> To debug the "test:unit" script, make sure the %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% string is specified as the first argument for the node command you'd like to debug.
>   For example:
>
> ```
>  "scripts": {
>    "start": "node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% server.js"  
>  }
> ```
>
> myapp@0.1.0 test:unit C:\Users\c-jay\myapp
>   vue-cli-service test:unit
>
> PASS  tests/unit/example.spec.js

**Configuration:**

- WebStorm 2018.2.4
- Vue CLI v3.0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [cli-plugin-jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest#debugging-tests) and [npm tasks debug in WebStorm](http://pavelpolyakov.com/2016/05/01/webstorm-npm-tasks-debug/) I've edited the npm test:unit call in the scripts-section of my package.json to:

```
"test:unit": "node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js test:unit"
```

And webstorm hits the breakpoints as expected. This is for Windows. On Mac should it be:

```
"test:unit": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js test:unit"
```